# Errcode 34 - Function is not available during Nightly Updates

Tags: jackhenry-jxchange

What is the recommended way to check for the following error returning from TrnAdd:

```
<FaultMsgRec>
<ErrCode>34</ErrCode>
<ErrCat>Error</ErrCat>
<ErrDesc>Function is not available during Nightly Updates</ErrDesc>
<ErrLoc>DDCRDRADD</ErrLoc>
</FaultMsgRec>
</FaultRecInfoArray>
```

We'd like to gracefully predict when a fault might otherwise occur.

We attempted to post a a transaction via TrnAdd, granted this was in the test/DMZ site for Silverlake development, but what occurs on the host during nightly updates. Other cores have a "memo" mode that allows posting during overnight updates, is that a possiblity here - and how do we find whether it is required before posting?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

This could vary depending upon which core and bank you're attempting to post the transaction on.  Each bank should have a regularly scheduled nightly processing window where transaction are limited.  This window is usually 1.5 to 2 hours.

I would add that the SilverLake core is adding this functionality (along with other jX operations) that can occur during that nightly processing in the 2023 core release.